# JQuery Disable Button if multiple file field empty

Tags: jquery

I have three file fields, and I want to disable my submit button unless the three of them not empty like this picture

[image]

I manage to disable the button, but the button become enable when I chose only one file, I want the button disabled until 3 files are chosen.

This is my code for the form:

```
<form>
    <label for="spd">Lampiran SPD</label>
      <input type="file" name="spd" id="spd" />
      <label for="smj">Lampiran SMJ</label>
      <input type="file" name="smj" id="smj" />
      <label for="tiket">Lampiran Tiket</label>
      <input type="file" name="tiket" id="tiket" />
  <input name="status" type="hidden" id="status" value="Pending" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" disabled />
</form>
```

and this is my code for the script I have used:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false); 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
    if( $('#spd').val() != '' && $('#smj').val() != '' && $('#tiket').val() != '' )
    {
      $('#button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <label for="spd">Lampiran SPD</label>
      <input type="file" name="spd" id="spd" /><br>
      <label for="smj">Lampiran SMJ</label>
      <input type="file" name="smj" id="smj" /><br>
      <label for="tiket">Lampiran Tiket</label>
      <input type="file" name="tiket" id="tiket" /><br>
  <input name="status" type="hidden" id="status" value="Pending" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" disabled />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:file').change(function(){
       if ($("#spd").val()!="" && $("#smj").val()!="" && $("#tiket").val()!="") 
       {
          $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false); 
       } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope it didn't work, it still enable the button when i just pick only one file field

Comment: can you share your whole jquery code which you are trying?

Comment: i am sorry before, this answer are solving my problem too, i made a mistake when write the code thanks a lot shubhangee